# why the controller don't read an if function loading the parameters?

Tags: function, controller, yii2

this is my create function in my controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $searchModel = new AutoriSearch();
        $model = new Autori();
        $model->RIDUtente = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        $model->Accettazione='SI';

        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
            
        $model->modified = date( 'y-m-d' );
        $model->creator_aut = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        $model->Utenteup_autori = Yii::$app->user->getId();
        if ($model->IParte) {
            $model->CampoRicerca = $model->IParte." ".$model->IIParte." ".$model->Prefisso." ".$model->Qualificazione." ".$model->IIEnte." ".$model->Sigla;
        }
            if($model->Accettazione == "" || $model->Accettazione == 'SI' ){
                $model->RIDAutore = $model->IDAutore;
            }
        $model->save();
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->IDAutore]);
    }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,

        ]);
    }
```

The problem is that the record is not saved, and the system don't enter in the if function "if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) )". So this is a problem. In others controller it gives me no error, for this controller it gives me the error. This is strange. Can anyone help me fast please? It's very important!!!! Thank you.

This is the form:

```
<div class="autori-form">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'action' => ['index'],
        'method' => 'get',
        'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
        
    ]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'IParte', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>'width:190px; height: 30px;'])->label('I Parte del nome') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'IIParte', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'position: relative; top: -63px; left: 360px;font-size: 12px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:190px; position: relative; position: relative; top: -58px; left: 360px;'])->label('Autori:<br>II Parte del nome') ?>
    
    <?= $form->field($model, 'IIEnte', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'width: 100px; position: relative; top: -120px; left: 800px;font-size: 12px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:190px; position: relative; top: -116px; left: 800px;'])->label('Enti: Ente subordinato') ?>
<div style="position: relative; top: -120px;">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'Prefisso', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:300px'])->label('Appellativi o altra parte del nome') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Sigla', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:300px'])->label('Sigla dell\'ordine') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Qualificazione', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:300px'])->label('Qualificazioni') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Fonte', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:300px']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'RIDTipoAutore', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px;']])->dropdownList(
        TipiAutore::find()
        ->select(['TipoAutore'])
        ->indexBy('IDTipoAutore')
        ->column(),
        ['prompt'=>'', 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:300px']
    )->label('Tipo Autore') ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'Accettazione', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px;']])->dropdownList(
        Autori::find()
        ->select(['Accettazione'])
        ->indexBy('Accettazione')
        ->column(),
        ['style'=>' height: 30px; width:300px', 'onchange' => 'accettato(this)'] 
    )->label('Accettazione') ?>   

    

    <?php //$form->field($model, 'CampoRicerca')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    
    <?= $form->field($model, 'RIDUtente')->hiddenInput(['value'=> Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->label(false) ?>

     <?= $form->field($model, 'RIDAutore', ['labelOptions'=>['style'=>'font-size: 12px; position: relative; top: -28px;']])->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'style'=>' height: 30px; width:300px; position: relative; top: -28px;', 'disabled' => true])->label('Forma accettata') ?>
    </div>
     <a name="button" id="btnMostra" style="position: relative; top: -199px; left: 540px; cursor: pointer;">Clicca per ricercare la forma accettata</a> 

    <script>
        function accettato(select) {
           console.log(select,$(select));
           $("#autori-ridautore").prop("disabled", $(select).val()!="NO"); 
        }
    </script>

    
    <?= Html::hiddenInput( 'modified', strtotime("now") ); ?>

    <div class="form-group" style="position: relative; top: -170px; left: 860px; width: 200px;">
        <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Salva'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= Html::a('Annulla', ['autori/index'], ['class'=>'btn btn-info']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

RULES OF Autori.php:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['RIDUtente', 'modified', 'RIDTipoAutore'], 'required'],
            [['RIDUtente', 'RIDAutore', 'RIDTipoAutore', 'creator_aut'], 'integer'],
            [['IParte', 'IIEnte'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['IIParte', 'Qualificazione'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['Prefisso'], 'string', 'max' => 30],
            [['Sigla'], 'string', 'max' => 10],
            [['Accettazione'], 'string', 'max' => 2],
            [['CampoRicerca'], 'string', 'max' => 400],
            [['Fonte'], 'string', 'max' => 3200],
            [['modified'], 'string', 'max' => 8],
        ];
    }
```

RULES OF AutoriSearch Model:

public function rules()

```
{
    return [
        [['IDAutore', 'RIDUtente', 'RIDAutore', 'RIDTipoAutore', 'creator_aut'], 'integer'],
        [['autoreMix', 'IParte', 'IIParte', 'Prefisso', 'Qualificazione',
        'IIEnte', 'Sigla', 'Accettazione', 'CampoRicerca',
        'Fonte', 'modified'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

Comment: please provide detail of $_POST

Comment: if I use var_dump($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) it gives me BOOL(FALSE). I try to give this if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post(), ' ') ) but nothing.

Comment: please show me this: var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post())

Comment: It gives me this: "array(0) { }"

Comment: So your problem is you form that it's not posting data

Comment: please add form details and model rules() function to your question

Comment: I add the form in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your forms method is get but you are getting data by post and this is incompatible

```
 'method' => 'get',

 $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()
```